# Hbase: I cluster hbase in Distributed mode and starting fine but when i run hbase shell I can't create table

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm so newby in hbase cluster , I cluster hbase in Distributed mode and starting fine but when i run hbase shell I can't create table this error is shown:
[image]

my base-site.xml configuration is

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.master</name>
  <value>matser:60000</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
  <value>hdfs://hadoop-namnode:54310/hbase</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>master</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientport</name>
  <value>2222</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
  <value>usr/local/hbase/temp</value>
</property>
```

could you please help me ?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`The version of Hbase should compatible to Hadoop version.Downgrade the Hbase it'll work fine.`